# Linking to Structure Pages in Wygwam: How to not use full URL?

Tags: structure, wygwam, links

I have a staging site running at a URL like client.clearbold.com.

I'm using FocusLab's Config, so all my paths and domains are dynamic.

When I link text in a Wygwam field, and choose a Structure Page or a Structure Listing entry, the full URL, including http://client.clearbold.com, is stored in the Wygwam field's contents.

How do I keep this from happening? We'll end up with a site with 100s of links to a Staging subdomain instead of the live URL.

**Updated:** I've confirmed this is fixed in 2.7. Surprised I haven't seen this before, though I'm wondering how many links were applied within content fields on previous projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all handled auto-magically. As long as you don't create links in source mode, it'll work when you change the domain/address/environment as of Wygwam 2.7.

See Also: [Dynamic Filepaths to Assets Files in Wygwam Fields](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5416/dynamic-filepaths-to-assets-files-in-wygwam-fields)

Comment: But I'm seeing them in Source mode, and when I copy the database down to dev and follow those links, they go to the Staging URL, not my local URL.

Comment: Right; that's what threw me off and made and led me to post my question. It "just worked" when we recently moved our site from development, to staging, to production.

Comment: The full URLs are in the database as well. This is Structure, not Assets.

Comment: Yes; I'm reading what you're saying... links to Structure pages in Wygwam fields continued working (despite showing as full URL's in source mode) when we moved from dev/staging/production across different domains.

Comment: So this has been an issue that's just been fixed? I'm on 2.6.3. I don't recall this happening in other sites.

Comment: The changelog indicates there were changes to how page URL's are handled in 2.7; suspect you'll need Lisa or Brandon to hop in here and clarify things further.  All I can tell you is that it worked just fine for us (sans links that were copy/pasted between two fields in source mode) using Wygwam 2.7 with links to Structure pages.

Comment: Yes, there were definitely changes surrounding Page URLs in 2.7; I'm not surprised that it addresses this particular issue for you.  Definitely, as Nick said, make sure you're not in source mode when saving though. :)

Comment: And your team is hard at work so it'll work even in source mode, right Lisa? ;)

Comment: Nick, CKEditor's source mode has some special applications regardless of Wygwam.  I'll bring this up to the team, but a change to that has implications for people using it the way it has been as well.  I know you have a bug report in about that, I'd love it if you'd send in more details about how you'd rather see that work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but different issue in my environment. Because my site is being reverse-proxied into another domain and uses CE-Cache, all links created with the "Structure" link type in Wygwam were getting cached with the Origin domain.

My fix was to add a line to wygwam/helper.php right after line 948:

```
$urls[] = str_replace("origindomain.com","destinationdomain.com",$page[4]);
```

This effectively ensured that all of those full-path Structure links generated within Wygwam fields rendered the destination domain rather than the Origin that's read by Akamai.

Comment: That could be helpful for the ones I'm stuck with. Thanks!